How to connect a wallet to a dapp while in developement?
I have used npx create-solana-dapp when the app was ready to view i pasted the IP into the browser but I'm not able to connect any wallet... whenever i click on the connect wallet button it show whats on the image below, can someone guide me ?


Which browser wallets do you have installed? Any of them should be automatically showing there.
